# Как в PHP организовать отображение шагов в работе скрипта в браузере?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Есть список действий : что-то скачать, куда-то поместить и дождаться выполнения анализа скаченного.
Как в РНР сделать так чтобы при запуске всех действий поочередно отображалась бы информация о статусе выполненного действия ?
Если в ручную, то понятно что после запуска 1 действия через Ajax отправляю инструкцию Jquery о смене цвета конкретного элемента.
А вот как сделать в цикле не знаю. Могу только предположить что нужен вызов JS функции в браузере которая будет в цикле через API сервера вызывать необходимую функцию на backend с передачей той номера теста, ожидания результата, выполнения JQ инструкций по раскарске и отправки следующего запроса. В принципе вроде должно работать.
Есть более элегантное решение на стороне backend ? Может сторонняя библиотека какая ...

Comment: Еще как вариант - соединение через Websockets

Comment: каким образом из РНР-скрипта соединиться с браузером и на нем изменить цвет конкретного элемента ? Приведите пример, пожалуйста.